# PHP CURL freezes on exec for Vimeo

Tags: php, vimeo, oembed

I've got some inherited code that uses the [OEmbed PHP Library](https://code.google.com/p/oembed-php/source/browse/trunk/class_oembed.php) to get the embed code for a Vimeo video. As of sometime today (1/31/2014) it started freezing when [curl_exec](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php) function is called within that library. Before today this code has been working perfectly fine. Thinking it is some problem with the server I brought the code to my local development machine and to my surprise it freezes there as well.

To try to come up with a simple reproducible bit of code I extracted just the curl download of the JSON info into the following script:

```
<?php

$url = "http://vimeo.com/api/oembed.json?url=http%3A%2F%2Fvimeo.com%2F64279006&maxwidth=&maxheight=&format=json";

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);

if($data = curl_exec($ch)){
  $http_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

  if($http_code >= 200 && $http_code < 300){
    $result["success"] = true;
    $result["data"] = $data;
    $result["http_code"] = $http_code;
  }else{
    $result["success"] = false;
    $result["http_code"] = $http_code;
    $result["url"] = $url;
  }
}else{
  $result["success"] = false;
  $result["curl_error_code"] = curl_errno($ch);
};

curl_close($ch);

print_r($result);
```

Interesting enough if I change URL to "http://vimeo.com/api/oembed.json?url=http%3A%2F%2Fvimeo.com%2F64279006", "http://vimeo.com/api/oembed.json" or even just "http://vimeo.com/" then I get the same behavior. But if I change it some some other non vimeo URL it works fine.

Anybody have any idea why it might be freezing up?

Answer (score 0):

Exact same problem here. Started today. I can curl the same URL from the command line, but when I hit it from PHP it freezes. I can curl to YouTube fine. Just not Vimeo. WTF.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem this afternoon on our server: vimeo slow, and our server almost freezed